# error: uuid is not a function in react native

Tags: react-native, uuid

I am getting an error which drives me crazy in react native:

imports:

```
     import 'react-native-get-random-values';
     import { parse as uuidParse, stringify as uuidStringify, v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

executing code

```
      const uuidBytes = uuidParse('6ec0bd7f-11c0-43da-975e-2a8ad9ebae0b');  
      console.log(uuidBytes);  
  
      const uuidString = uuidStringify(uuidBytes);  
      console.log(uuidString);  
  
      const newUuid = uuidv4(); 
      console.log(newUuid);
```

my output is:

> LOG  [110, 192, 189, 127, 17, 192, 67, 218, 151, 94, 42, 138, 217, 235, 174, 11]

> LOG  6ec0bd7f-11c0-43da-975e-2a8ad9ebae0b

> ERROR  [TypeError: undefined is not a function]

you see the two functions are working one of them not

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same code But on my end, it is working perfectly and giving me the logs of all these 3 functions.

Try to remove the cache and clean the gradle build.

This is the version of those 2 packages that I've tried

"react-native-get-random-values": "^1.9.0"

"uuid": "^9.0.0"